# How i can use lottie files in my next js app

Tags: reactjs, animation, next.js, lottie, nextjs-image

I want add some animation on my next js App ,How I can do, I try using  **lottie-react**  ,but there are some performence issue

Just expection any other npm for only next js and what i can  do to resolve performencce issues

Comment: What performance issues are you referring to? Loading time, frame rate, etc?

Comment: App takes too much time in loading after using lottie-react package

Comment: How big are the lotties? They should, if exported correctly and vectors are used, be under 500kbs. 

If bigger you could dynamically import them with a placeholder image then replace with lottie after load.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.